I would like to disable the "Alt+a" keyboard shortcut in konsole for Kde Neon
As it says in my title, I would like to disable the "Alt+a" keyboard shortcut of my "Konsole" terminal in Kde Neon.
For some reason every time I press "alt+a" the Konsole menu opens and I don't understand why. I mean, that keyboard shortcut doesn't exist (F10 is open menu) and I've been deleting various alt-related keyboard shortcuts to see if that would fix the problem but I did not succeed.
I want to get rid of that keyboard shortcut since I have a module installed in my terminal that uses that shortcut but that shortcut does not work because Kde uses it to open the menu.
